# unexpected results from timespan in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, timespan

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(reader1["cur_time"].ToString()));
int a = ts.Minutes;
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
MessageBox.Show(ts.Milliseconds.ToString());
```

By subtracting time it gives me 8 minutes which is correct. but converted these 8 minutes in milliseconds not give correct answer. If I convert 8 minutes in milliseconds it should be 480000 milliseconds but the above code gives me 708 answer.

Comment: Use `ts.TotalMilliseconds` instead. You're getting the fractional portion of the time, not the time represented in milliseconds. You should be using `ts.TotalMinutes` as well.

Comment: thank you very much it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading out the millisecond part of the `TimeSpan` and not the total milliseconds the span represents.

Change

```
ts.Milliseconds.ToString();
```

to

```
ts.TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
```

It might include some additional milliseconds depending on what `DateTime.Now` is and the parsed cur_time.